# Accessing credential in the script executing from Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute the following command in PowerShell:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <computerName> -FilePath script.ps1 -Credential $cred
```

Using `Invoke-Command` I am executing a PowerShell script "script.ps1" providing credentials in `$cred`.

Is there any way I can use the passed variable `$cred` in the above `Invoke-Command`, in the script again without asking a user about credentials?
i.e. something like below:

`script.ps1`:

```
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the script accept a credential parameter:

`script.ps1`:

```
Param([PSCredential]$Credential)
New-PSSession ... -Credential $Credential
```

and invoke it while passing `$cred` as an argument like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -FilePath script.ps1 -ArgumentList $cred -Credential $cred
```